# Can I configure TestStack.White UI test cases in CI\CD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, teststack

I am in the process of configuring Azure DevOps CI\CD pipeline for my WPF desktop application.  UI test cases of the WPF application are written using TestStack.White framework.  Is it possible to use test cases written usingTestStack.White framework in DevOps CI\CD pipeline?  If yes, how can I configure TestStack.White UI test cases in CI\CD pipeline?  How can I publish test results from my TestStack.White test cases to DevOps?  Could you point me to a code example ?

Comment: Did you try out below solution? Any updates?

Comment: Yes. The below solution is working fine for me. But, The given sample is an unit test using TestStack.White Framework and able to test it by using VSTest in DevOps Build pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can run TestStack.White UI test in CI\CD pipeline and below is the configuration about build pipeline.
[image]
[image]

According to the code sample, I think you can get this sample to test. https://github.com/xingyu217/TestStackDemo